# Blinking caret inside form

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to add a blinking caret / cursor inside the form in a twitter bootstrap 3 site. There is a codepen for the html and css but I need help on where to add the code, if the code works with bootstrap? I'm new and eager to learn but I have browsed and browsed and got no results.

The codepen is here 
http://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/GnLBq

```
html
<span class="blinking-cursor">|</span>

css
.blinking-cursor {
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 30px;
color: #2E3D48;
-webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
-moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
-ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
-o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes "blink" {
from, to {
color: transparent;
}
50% {
color: black;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
from, to {
color: transparent;
}
50% {
color: black;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
from, to {
color: transparent;
}
50% {
color: black;
}
}

@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
from, to {
color: transparent;
}
50% {
color: black;
}
}

@-o-keyframes "blink" {
from, to {
color: transparent;
}
50% {
color: black;
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you want this to be added? An input field?

Comment: Inside the form where the user enters their email address, for example just before the placeholder "enter email address"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the input and the blinking icon into a container, then position the blinking icon inside the input.

```css
/* The container */
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Ensure the font-size is the same as the blinking icon */
.input-container input {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding:0 5px;
}

/* Position it where you want. Must be position: absolute! */
.input-container .blinking-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px; /* The same as padding on the input */
}

/* This will hide the blinking cursor when the user clicks on the input */
.input-container input:focus + .blinking-cursor{
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* The code below is from the codepen: http://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/GnLBq */
.blinking-cursor {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #2E3D48;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="blinking-cursor">|</span>
</div>
```

You may want to edit the styles further, but this will put you in the direction you're wanting to go.

Comment: Wes, Thanks very much, just tried it and very happy with the results, Ill give the styling a little play, but its working.